# How to put information messages?

Tags: html, css

I don't know how that's called, I'm searching but I can't find it anywhere but I know there is an easy way to do it.

How do I simply put one of those information boxes that points to my `<div>`?

Like this but with text inside it:
https://static.thenounproject.com/png/153178-200.png  and pointing to my div

Comment: What have you tried so far? Edit your question body to show what code you have.

Comment: You are talking about popovers? There is a way using bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/popovers/  Or you are talking about tooltips? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/tooltips/

Comment: Yes! that's it! ty ty XD I just wanted to know the name of it. Sorry for the silly question

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with before elements like this: https://jsfiddle.net/h836fdnL/6/

```
<div class="block"></div>


.block {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  position: relative;
  background: green;
}
.block::before {
  display: block;
  background-image: url('https://static.thenounproject.com/png/153178-200.png');
  content: 'Hello I am text';
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  top: -100px;
  left: 0;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Bootstrap Alerts? You can also use `.show()` and `.hide()` on the alerts with jQuery.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
  A simple info alert—check it out!
</div>
```